# SQLAlchemy how to check if a value is between the values in two columns?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I check if the condition value is between column1 and column2?

MySQL:

```
select
    *
from
    tablename
where
    '2014-01-01' between start_date and end_date
```

SQLAlchemy:

```
select(
  [table.c.id],
  and_('2014-01-01'.between(start_date, end_date))
)
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import literal

literal('2014-01-01').between(x, y)
```